# KeyError: "['FK'] not in index" and A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Description:
I am currently working on a data scraping project where I aim to collect data for multiple seasons of the Premier League. However, I have encountered a KeyError that I cannot seem to resolve. Surprisingly, when I scrape data for a single team, the error does not occur. I believe the issue lies in the absence of the "FK" column, as indicated by the error message.

Here's a breakdown of my situation:

Objective:
Scraping Premier League data for multiple seasons.

Approach:

- I have scraped DataFrame named matches containing data for various matches
- I also scraped DataFrame named shooting that holds shooting statistics
  for different teams and seasons, including columns such as "Date", "Sh", "SoT", "Dist", "FK","PK", and "PKatt".

Problem:
When attempting to merge the matches DataFrame with the shooting DataFrame on the "Date" column I  receive a KeyError stating "['FK'] not in index". This error suggests that the "FK" column is missing in the index of the shooting DataFrame. However, when scraping data for a single team, this error does not occur. here is the whole code:

```
standings_url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/Premier-League-Stats"

for year in years:
data = requests.get(standings_url)
time.sleep(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
time.sleep(1)
standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]

links = [l.get("href") for l in standings_table.find_all('a')]
links = [l for l in links if '/squads/' in l]
team_urls = [f"https://fbref.com{l}" for l in links]

previous_season = soup.select("a.prev")[0].get("href")
standings_url = f"https://fbref.com{previous_season}"

for team_url in team_urls:
    team_name = team_url.split("/")[-1].replace("-Stats", "").replace("-", " ")

    data = requests.get(team_url)
    matches = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Scores & Fixtures")[0]

    time.sleep(1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
    time.sleep(1)
    links = [l.get("href") for l in soup.find_all('a')]
    links = [l for l in links if l and 'all_comps/shooting/' in l]
    data = requests.get(f"https://fbref.com{links[0]}")
    shooting = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Shooting")[0]
    shooting.columns = shooting.columns.droplevel()

    try:
        team_data = matches.merge(shooting[["Date", "Sh", "SoT", "Dist", "FK", "PK", "PKatt"]], on="Date")
    except ValueError:
        continue
    team_data = team_data[team_data["Comp"] == "Premier League"]
    
    team_data["Season"] = year
    team_data["Team"] = team_name
    all_matches.append(team_data)
    time.sleep(2)
```

here is the [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GkYPa-_Z7sS-QBJDRJGpM8CCsU25wsmW?usp=sharing) to the colab

There is also A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.